# Negative index of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I found some code that uses negative array indices. Then, I try to use it, nothing special happens. It behaves normally. I can retrieve all elements by using a standard `foreach` loop.

So, what is the purpose to use those negative indices? And when should I use it?

Comment: In PHP, negative keys stay integers: `is_int( key( array( -11 => '')))===true` or https://3v4l.org/eJGjV, not like JavaScript, where negative numbers become string keys: `o={}; o[-5]='-'; o[0]='0'; o[+5]='+'; o;` (paste to console).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An array, in PHP, is actually just some kind of an ordered map : you can use integers *(positive or negative)*, but also strings, as keys -- and there will not be much of difference.

Answer (score 23):

Negative array keys have no special meaning in PHP, as (like any other value) they can be the keys of an associative array.

```
$arr = array(-1 => 5);
echo $arr[-1];
```

Some of PHP's standard library functions (the ones that expect regular arrays with only natural integer indices), however, take negative offsets to mean "count from the end instead of the beginning". [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is one such example.

Answer (score 21):

[From 7.1 onward](https://wiki.php.net/rfc#php_71), we have an important and practical special case, i.e. when using the array syntax to access particular *characters of a string from backwards*:

```
$str = "123";
echo "LAST CHAR of str == '$str[-1]'<br>"; // '3'

//$empty = "";
//echo "LAST CHAR of empty == '$empty[-1]'<br>"; // '', Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -1
```

Comment: In PHP5, `E_NOTICE Uninitialized string offset: -1`

Answer (score 15):

Negative array indexes don't have a special meaning (i.e. get the last/second last element etc.) in PHP.
To get the last element of an array use:

```
$last = end($array);
```

To get the second last add:

```
$secondLast = prev($array);
```

Keep in mind that these functions [modify the arrays internal pointer](http://php.net//manual/en/function.end.php). To reset it use:

```
reset($array);
```

Comment: You can get the last element more directly. `$someArray[count($someArray) - 1]`

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge That only works if the array keys are sequential order starting with `0`.

Answer (score 4):

In `PHP 8`:

> Any array that has a number n as its first numeric key will use n+1
> for its next implicit key, even if n is negative.

So if the first key is negative `-33`, the next key will be `-32` (not `0`) .. and so on.

See the difference here

https://3v4l.org/8MXq9