# Updating a PHP Array, and updating server side

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm messing around with some php and unfamiliar with how updating an array works properly. Here is what I have at the moment:

index.php

```
<form action="register.php" method="get">
register > 
    <input name="reg_username" type="text" />
    <input name="reg_password" type="password" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

register.php

```
    <?php
    $username = $_GET["reg_username"];
    $password = $_GET["reg_password"];
        include('data/user_data.php');
        if(isset($users[$username])):
            echo "this username is already taken!";
        else: 
            array_push($users, $username, $username, $password);            
        endif;  
?>
```

user_data.php

```
<?php $users = array(
dextermb => array("dextermb", "password"),
tonymb => array("tonymb", "password2")
)
?>
```

I'd like to make sure that when updating the array it stays in the same format as the ones already within it.

`"username" => array("username","password")`

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you are working with passwords you should use the post method instead of get, The post method is more secure as it will not go through the url.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard about the difference :P Just using it to make sure that everything is working properly (like no typos, which might make me think there's an error in code) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new element to your array with the username as the key and an array containing the username and password:

```
if(isset($users[$username])):
    echo "this username is already taken!";
else: 
    $users[$username] = array($username, $password);
endif;
```

Comment: to save the new array input to the user_data.php from the server, or instance - if i were to go back to index.php and attempt to login with the new 'user' it would comeback with 'not in array'

Comment: If you need to add this user to the array *permanently* you need to re-create that file from scratch with the new values in that array. A better way to do this is to use a database as that is what they are for.

Comment: Yeah suppose, but its always an adventure using arrays and objects

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this?

```
$users[$username] = array($username, $password );
```

To make it simple in use , you can try below code also

```
$users[$username] = $password; // If you have no other data in array
```

Comment: It is not a good solution what if in some cases $username was a negative number.It's a best practice to always use constants for keys in arrays and prevent using variables.

Comment: Lol.. Username is negative?  It's very stranger.

Comment: It's a general consideration.When you are testing your code sure $username may never be a negative number but in production manner it should consider as a risk.

Comment: Can you please check this link: ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889663/negative-index-of-array-on-php

Answer (score 0):

[`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/array_push) only works for non-associative arrays. You explicitly set the array key and its associated value with:

```
$array[$key] = array();
```

As a result, your code should look like:

```
if(isset($users[$username])):
    echo "this username is already taken!";
else: 
    $users[$username] = array($username, $password);
```